# Callbacks: java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: android, android-activity, callback, fragment

**Problem:** I need to pass a `callback` from a `fragment` to an `acitvity`. Unfortunately I get that stack trace:

Why do I get that error? I have found some posts with a similiar problem. Unfortunately I still do not understand why I get that issue.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: 

    com.stack.overflow, PID: 26190
                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.stack.overflow/com.stack.overflow.main.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.stack.overflow.main.MainActivity cannot be cast tocom.stack.overflow.ReviewMaschineFragment$Callbacks
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:com.stack.overflow.main.MainActivity cannot be cast to com.stack.overflow.reviewmaschine.ReviewMaschineFragment$Callbacks
                                                                           at com.stack.overflow.reviewmaschine.ReviewMaschineFragment.onAttach(ReviewMaschineFragment.java:101)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1039)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.setLastIn(BackStackRecord.java:795)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.calculateFragments(BackStackRecord.java:818)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:676)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1671)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:388)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:619)
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1236)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6006)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

My `fragment` class:

```
public class ReviewMaschineFragment extends Fragment {

    (...)

    public interface Callbacks {
        void onUserChangedData();
    }

    private Callbacks mCallbacks;

    (...)

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mCallbacks = (Callbacks) context;
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mCallbacks = null;
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    }

}
```

My `activity` class:

```
public class ReviewActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ReviewMaschineFragment.Callbacks{
                       
    (...)

    @Override
    public void onUserChangedData() {
        // Do something. 
    }

    (...)

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `MainActivity` is using `ReviewMaschineFragment` but it does not implement `Callbacks`.

Change your `onAttach` method to assign a callback only if the activity implements `Callbacks`:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    if (context instanceof Callbacks) {
        mCallbacks = (Callbacks) context;
    }
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}
```

Now when you use `mCallbacks` check first that it is not null

```
if (mCallbacks != null) {
    mCallbacks.onUserChangedData();
}
```

Comment: Now I am able to run the app again, but the callback is still not called. Do I have to change the moment when the callbacks get initialized?

Comment: If you want the callback to be called in your `MainActivity`, then implement `Callbacks` as you did with `ReviewActivity`